# Wrapping a package in golang

Tags: go, package

Imagine a package that exports some structs and some functions.

If I wanted to make a wrapper around that package, so that it could be used as a drop-in,  should I recreate the structs with the old struct embedded in it? Example:

```
package foo

type Foo struct {
    Field string
}

func DoSomething() {

}
```

---

```
package bar

import foo

type Foo struct {
    foo.Foo
}

func DoSomething() {
    foo.DoSomething()
}
```

Is there a better way? Is this the idiomatic way?

Comment: The most idiomatic approach is to define interface{} types that describe the methods your drop-in type has to satisfy, like net/http's `Handler`.

Comment: Unfortunately the interfaces work only for methods of structs, not for package scoped functions.

Comment: You seem to know what needs to be done -- you need to mirror all the exported symbols. Embedding is just a form of automatic delegation, so you can use it where it works, and do it manually where it doesn't. There's no magic to be had here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems like this is the idiomatic way. No magic.

```
func DoSomething() {
    foo.DoSomething()
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I think not. Just use the original package, you could use alias if you want to use your own version.

Let's say currently your code is:

```
import (
    "abc.com/package/foo"
)

func CallFoo() {
    foo.DoSomething()
}
```

You can replace foo with bar by alias the import, other codes remain the same.

```
import (
    foo "abc.com/package/bar" // this is alias
)

func CallFoo() {
    foo.DoSomething()
}
```

Comment: Yes but my question was about the design of the package.

Comment: You mean you want to create a new package which has the same interface as the previous one? 

If that's the case, it depends on what you want to do in your new package. From your question, seems don't need to create a new package as the functionality is the same. If not same, you can do whatever you like write a brand new package but with same interface.